# How do I use unicode in this?

Tags: c#

I have some code that's returning a null symbol when I try to add unicode to it, anyone know why?

```
string first = "\uD83D\uDC4A\uD83D\uDC4A\uD83D\uDC4A";
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  Console.Write(first[i % 3] + "\r");
  Thread.Sleep(100);
}
Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

I'm basically trying to get 3 emojis to changing rapidly, in one character of text, but it's returning null when I use unicode characters.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Ah, I tried it out with using \U0001F44A for 3 characters, and it returned null characters

Comment: What symbol is that supposed to be, may be it's invalid?

Comment: I missed out a part of the code, updated post. Should we move to chat?

Comment: just to be sure, @Tabogachi, are you using windows command line for the output window? if so, you need to [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line) to show unicode properly.

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm using a mac, and just opening the VS terminal.

Comment: I'm assuming that I have to render it as UTF16 somehow..anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emoji symbols are complex, usually an emoji symbol is not a single character but a sequence with variable length.

You can find the [specification here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/).

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/geniuszxy/9bb507f03eb17526d4f58f3c387031b3) to split a string into pieces.

```
var list = new List<string>();
var itor = new EmojiIterator(first);
while(itor.MoveNext())
    list.Add(itor.Sequence);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Console.Write(list[i % list.Count] + "\r");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Please notice that I've tested this code on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PBq8hA), but I'm not sure whether if the VS terminal on Mac can render emojis.

---

[image: Screenrecord]

Comment: Hey! I'm a little confused on what this does. I ran the dotnetfiddle and it just outputs: " r    r    r    r    r   ".

Comment:  = `\uD83D\uDC4A`, the website doesn't support `\r`, so it outputs every thing in a line.

Comment: I've tried it out but it seems to show one emoji for a breaf second then end the program

Comment: What's your expectation?

Comment: hmmm. the best way I can describe it is that in a single character, the emoji changes every few miliseconds, until the loop ends. Kinda like some sort of casino style change.

Comment: Did you try your example in the question? If so it only contains one emoji.

Comment: I tried `\uD83D\uDC4A\u270c\ufe0f\u270b` which contains the fist, victory hand and regular hand.

Comment: I don't have a mac, maybe the terminal will buffer the output, you might try "1234" to see if it changes the number. Added a gif to show what I got in vscode's terminal.

Comment: Figured it out! I didn't add a sleep to the program and it instead just set it all at the same time. Thanks shingo!